# Return same data from set_fact as var

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

I am trying to create a dictionary. When using var things are working as expected. However Set_fact its like something is being ignored, which I cannot isolate.

Reading Jinja2 manual, multiple iterations

```
---
- hosts: localbox   gather_facts: false

  vars:
      app_servers: 5
      ipaddress_base: "192.168.0"
      rmi_portbase: 10000
      host_info: |
        {% set res = [] -%}
        {%- for number in range(1,app_servers + 1) -%}
          {% set ignored = res.extend([{
            'hostname': 'app' + number|string,
            'ipaddress': ipaddress_base + '.' + number|string,
            'rmi_port': rmi_portbase|int + ( number * 10)
            }]) -%}
        {%- endfor %}
        {{ res }}

  tasks:

    - name: thing
      set_fact: 
        thing2: "{% set res = [] -%}
        {%- for number in range(1,app_servers + 1) -%}
          {% set ignored = res.extend([{
            'hostname': 'app' + number|string,
            'ipaddress': ipaddress_baase + '.' + number|string,
            'rmi_port': rmi_portbase|int + ( number * 10)
            }]) -%}
        {%- endfor %}
        {{ res }}"

    - debug: var=host_info[0].hostname
    - debug: var=thing2[0]
```

I expect results like host_info from thing2.

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "host_info[0].hostname": "app1"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "thing2[0]": " "
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the playbook you have posted, it should fail with the following error:

> TASK [thing]
>
> ---
>
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option
>   with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ipaddress_baase' is
>   undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/lars/
>   tmp/ansible/playbook.yml': line 25, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in
>   the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line
>   appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: thing\n      ^ her e\n"}

And indeed, you have misspelled `ipaddress_base` as `ipaddress_baase` (note the extra `a`).  If you fix that typo and add modify the final `debug` task like this:

```
- debug: var=thing2
```

You should see the following output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "thing2": " [{'rmi_port': 10010, 'hostname': u'app1', 'ipaddress': u'192.168.0.1'}, {'rmi_port': 10020, 'hostname': u'app2', 'ipaddress': u'192.168.0.2'}, {'rmi_port': 10030, 'hostname': u'app3', 'ipaddress': u'192.168.0.3'}, {'rmi_port': 10040, 'hostname': u'app4', 'ipaddress': u'192.168.0.4'}, {'rmi_port': 10050, 'hostname': u'app5', 'ipaddress': u'192.168.0.5'}]"
}
```

What that is showing us is that `thing2` is a string, not a dictionary.  So when you task for `thing2[0]`, you're getting the character at position `0` of that string.

The *reason* it's a string instead of a dictionary is *because* of that leading space at index 0.  We can fix it by changing the terminal marker on your `endfor` statement from `%}` to `-%}` which will eat up any following whitespace:

```
- set_fact:
    thing2: "{% set res = [] -%}
    {%- for number in range(1,app_servers + 1) -%}
      {% set ignored = res.extend([{
        'hostname': 'app' + number|string,
        'ipaddress': ipaddress_baase + '.' + number|string,
        'rmi_port': rmi_portbase|int + ( number * 10)
        }]) -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
    {{ res }}"
```

With this and your original `debug` task, we see as output:

```
TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "host_info[0].hostname": "app1"
}

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "thing2[0]": {
        "hostname": "app1", 
        "ipaddress": "192.168.0.1", 
        "rmi_port": 10010
    }
}
```

---

Having said that, I would stop trying to use this technique to generate complex data structures because it is  -- as we have seen -- prone to errors.  I would write it like this:

```
- set_fact: 
    thing2: "{{ thing2|default([]) + [{
      'hostname': 'app' ~ item,
      'ipaddress': ipaddress_base ~ '.' ~ item,
      'rmi_port': rmi_portbase ~ (item * 10)}]
      }}"
  loop: "{{ range(1, app_servers+1)|list }}"
```

I think that's both simpler to implement and easier to read.